# how to stop that clipboard plugin bind again and again?

Tags: jquery, clipboard.js

I used the clipboardjs plugin two place in a same page.

```
require(["Clipboard"], function(Clipboard){
    var clipboard = new Clipboard('.copyLink');
    clipboard.on('success', function(e){
        alert("success");                               
        e.clearSelection();
    });

    clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
        alert("fail");
    });
});
```

when i copy something that will working correctly, if i click the first copy again and again that will working correctly.if i click the second copy after the first copy that that success function is execute twice time. I want that success will be execute only once for a click.

Comment: maybe You will need to call: clipboard.destroy();

Comment: but clipboard.destroy(); is throw an error.@Franco

Comment: Are you using `var clipboard`to declare both of them?

Comment: Now it is working correctly.Thanks